# How to disable Firefox from setting a homepage shortcut for every populer site I visit?

Tags: firefox

[image]

I want to have shortcuts, but, unlike Chrome, Firefox adds shortcuts automatically based on sites I frequent a lot (for example Wikipedia). How can I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it on Firefox's homepage with this.

Click a gear at the top right of the page:

[image: A screenshot of a Firefox start page with several popular page links visible towards the center. A small gear link is visible in the upper right corner of the same page.]

You will see something like this:

[image: A screenshot of options dealing with page shortcuts on the Firefox start page. There is a "Close" link in the upper right corner. The options included are a toggle button to turn these "Shortcuts" on or off, a combo box to select the number of sites to display that you "save or visit" and a checkbox to select whether to display sponsored shortcuts. There is also a "Recent Activity" toggle button for "a selection of recent sites and content". Lastly, there is a separate gear link to "Manage more settings" underneath these other options.]

Disable Shortcuts for prevent from showing all shortcuts including your recent pages, or only disable Recent activity to prevent from showing recent pages only. But if you keep Shortcuts on, some visited pages still be here.

Comment: This is weird. It's already turned off, but Firefox still adds to the shortcuts my recently visited websites.

https://i.ibb.co/2vP3YNW/123.png

Comment: I think you need to turn off Shortcuts.

Comment: But then I won't have shortcuts at all

Comment: I have rechecked the Settings - we can't force Firefox to hide visited sites. But at least you can turn off Recent activity, should it work? Sorry for this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first delete from history, then pin it and then unpin it, and finally dismiss it. It is a long process but it works! (I just found out a few seconds ago.)